# Generic Type not loading in IntelliJ

Tags: generics, intellij-idea

Most of us use IntelliJ. Here i am trying to declare BiConsumer, but why generics T & U not loading.
I need to give <> bracket and define generic type every time separately.
I tried to find solution on net, but no luck. Can anyone help why generic type not coming as placeholder to enter the type.

[image]